# C++ writing to real-time excel graph

Tags: c++, excel, graph, visual-studio-2013

I am developing a program in VS2013 C++ and currently I am writing values to a .csv file. I would like to plot these values in real-time so that I can have a visualization of them when running the program.

Can anyone point me towards a library to do this? My thoughts are an ODBC server that pipes to excel or something of the sort.

Comment: Why are you writing to a file, reading that file, then plotting? Why not cut out the middleman and just plot the data (and then write to file afterwards if you need to)?

Comment: You need to use OLE Automation if you would like to plot them in Excel.

Comment: Dr. Watson, that sounds good to me. Do you have any suggestions for how to go about plotting in real time?